# Huge mishap: Upgrade from 14.10 to 15.4 froze, now I cant get passed the login-screen

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

I tried to make an update from Kubuntu 14.10 to 15.4 via the Muon Updater. During installation (while installing cups to be precise), the muon window froze. I imagine it might have been because of some EULA I needed to except, however no window popped up and I couldn't press the button "terminal", because the application was frozen. So I terminated the muon window. But now muon can't be opened again and when I try to do the update via a konsole I get:

```
~$ sudo kubuntu-devel-release-upgrade
Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-IamTheUser" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0.
New Release of Ubuntu is searched for
No new Release found
```

Alternatively:

```
~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
[sudo] password for ...:
New Release of Ubuntu is searched for
No new Release found
```

Also:

```
~$ muon-updater
muon-updater: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And:

```
~$ sudo muon
muon: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Moreover, pressing Ctrl + Esc and searching for a process containing "muon" did not turn anything up.

Because of the earlier error I executed

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

but if I call the system settings I get the error (translated into English):

```
The command cannot be executed. The file or folder file:///usr/share/applications/kde4/systemsettings.desktop does not exist.
```

So I tried

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for ...: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: The resource is not available at the moment)
E: Locking of the administration folders (/var/lib/dpkg/) is not possible, is it used by a different process?
```

and thus

```
~$ pgrep dpkg
14527
~$ sudo kill 14527
~$ sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

Which now worked. However, trying to open the system settings, still produced the same error!

I rebooted the system by now. I get up until the login-screen, but when I put in my passwort it runs for a while and brings me back to the login-screen. I went into Going into recover mode and ran the dpkg repair packages menu  two times, until no packages where installed or deinstalled anymore. However, I still can't get passed the login-screen.

What should I do?